# project can't work in local server for magento

Tags: magento

I am new for magneto. I have one project in live server from that I want to use at localhost server

But it can't work

I have found Following Error and also can't run admin panel

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'windowsh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

what should i have to make changes for that and in which file ?

Comment: The username and password is incorrect.

Comment: You need grant privileges to the user if you want external access to database(ie. web pages).

Comment: try changing the database username/password in the app/etc/local.xml file

Comment: Looks like there is problem with your database configuration. Check your username, password and DBname in app/etc/local.xml